# Rails 3 routing and namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I want to have a namespaced controller called 'portal'.

in this will be nested resources such as companies and products.

I'd like routes like :

`/portal/:company_id/product/:id`  to work

I can get

`/portal/company/:company_id/product/:id` to work but would like to eliminate the 'company' in the url

Hope that is clear.  Please keep in mind that I need the namespaced module portal to exist.

Comment: What's the problem when you use 'match' ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could use `scope` to achieve what you want. Perhaps like this:

```
namespace "portal" do
  scope ":company_id" do
    resources :products
  end
end
```

That will generate the following routes:

```
    portal_products GET    /portal/:company_id/products(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"portal/products"}
                    POST   /portal/:company_id/products(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"portal/products"}
 new_portal_product GET    /portal/:company_id/products/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"portal/products"}
edit_portal_product GET    /portal/:company_id/products/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"portal/products"}
     portal_product GET    /portal/:company_id/products/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"portal/products"}
                    PUT    /portal/:company_id/products/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"portal/products"}
                    DELETE /portal/:company_id/products/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"portal/products"}
```

Edit: Accidentally used resource instead of resources. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the routes to nearly whatever you want if you spell them out directly, like this:

```
match '/portal/:company_id/product/:id', :to => 'companies_products#show'
```

The `:to` part specifies the controller and action to use, something that should match what you have in your routes now. If you're not sure what that is, `rake routes` will tell you its specific interpretation.